# How can I add an event to a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like certain elements on my site to emit a sound when clicked. I easily did that by adding an `audio` element with a `ref`, and a function that plays the `ref`s sound `onClick`.

```
const sound = require('../sounds/bird.mp3');
const soundRef = useRef(null);
const playSound = () => {
    soundRef.current.play();
}

return <div>
    <audio ref={soundRef}><source src={sound} /></audio>
    <img src="bird.png" onClick={playSound} />
</div>
```

Since I now found out I may need to reuse this, I decided to create an `Audio` component to encapsulate the clicked element. I'd like it to receive the sound's file name as a property:

```
<Audio soundName="bird">
    <div><img src="bird.png" /></div>
</Audio>
```

My problem is: in the `Audio` component, I get the `soundName` and `children` props and render the `{children`, but how do I add an `onClick` even to the child element, so it would trigger the `Audio` element `playSound` function?

What I currently have in the `Audio` component:

```
export default ({soundName, ...children}) => {
    const sound = require(`../sounds/${soundName}.mp3`);
    const soundRef = useRef(null);
    const playSound = () => {
        soundRef.current.play();
    }

    return <>
        <audio ref={soundRef}><source src={sound} /></audio>
        {children}    // <--- this is where I need to somehow add the event
    </>
}
```

I'm hoping I'm missing a tiny thing here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your `children` with something, like a `div`, who can listen for your event, something like:

```js
export default ({soundName, ...children}) => {
    const sound = require(`../sounds/${soundName}.mp3`);
    const soundRef = useRef(null);
    const playSound = () => {
        soundRef.current.play();
    }

    return <>
        <audio ref={soundRef}><source src={sound} /></audio>
        <div onClick={ playSound }>
            {children}    // <--- this is where I need to somehow add the event
        </div>
    </>
}
```

I think this covers most of your cases.

There might be a children which intercept the event before the `Audio` component and prevent the event propagation to the parent, something like:

```js
<Audio soundName="bird">
    <img
        src="bird.png"
        onClick={ event => {
            doSomethingOnThisImageClick()
            event.stopPropagation()
        }}
    />
</Audio>
```

If you know that this case might happen but you still want to play the file no matter what, you need to recognize the event in its capture phase, BEFORE the child component even know it, using the `Capture` variant of the event name, like:

```js
export default ({soundName, ...children}) => {
    const sound = require(`../sounds/${soundName}.mp3`);
    const soundRef = useRef(null);
    const playSound = () => {
        soundRef.current.play();
    }

    return <>
        <audio ref={soundRef}><source src={sound} /></audio>

        { /*      notice here?     */ }
        { /*           |           */ }
        { /*           v           */ }
        <div onClickCapture={ playSound }>
            {children}
        </div>
    </>
}
```

Comment: This works well! However, for design/CSS purposes, I don't really want to add an extra `div` there. Is there a way to add just the `onclick` event around the children, without an actual element?

Comment: Yes, you can clone the element(s) using `React.cloneElement` and replace the `onClick` handler with your stuff. Be careful though to keep track of other click handlers set by the user and to call those at the end of your `onClick` handler passing down the event. If you need more help, I'm here. Oh, and Happy New Year.